Jar location path for maven project
I want to configure my jar location independent of user folder path(C:\Users\CHE-QA01) as we are many people running the same project and need to update the above path when pulling from git repo.
I have configured my jar loc as per image
enter image description here
I have tried to add {$basedir} but it not working me.
How to configure the path irrespective of user...
Thanks in advance

Don't use images for text information in [so]. There are many similar questions already posted here. Try searching for them to see if the answers are helpful. But note that that is not the way Maven should be used.

Don't use system scoped dependencies, just... not ever. I would do this personally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28762617/424903 . Create a maven repository as part of your project and mvn install the dependencies there.

Assuming your artefact is not for public consumption, then you should run a artefact repository for your organisation.
For example, you can the Nexus repository easily: https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-repository
